# Which comic is this panel from showing Batman sitting at the BatComputer in the BatCave researching the Fortress of Solitude?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, batman

Which comic is this panel from? I found the image [here](https://casscain.fandom.com/wiki/File:BatcaveBatcopter.jpg).

[image: Bruce sitting at the Bat-Computer in the Bat-Cave researching the Fortress of Solitude]

Comment: I'm not sure if that even is the fortress. It doesn't look like any version I've seen. It might be Kandor

Comment: The bat computer in the image is semi-identical to [the design seen in the Justice League: Doom cartoon](https://skinwalker.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/batcomputer.jpg); https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_Doom

Comment: No help on the site, but this image (of Bruce revealing the batcave to the JLA?) is in a very similar art style from the same page; https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/casscain/images/0/03/BatcaveJLAReveal.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110520011909

Comment: That looks like the design of the bat computer fairly universally used for a while after No Man's Land. I had a look through some old comics, couldn't find a match. Also the image looks more like Atlantis, Kandor or Gorilla City to me.

Comment: Why are there scans of a picture of a bed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's from issue 2 of [Batman: City of Light](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_City_of_Light).

[image]

City of Light is a Batman storyline written by Arnold Pander, Jacob Pander, and Mark Paniccia, with illustrations by the Pander brothers. It was published as an eight issue mini-series. The story deals with a mad architect redesigning Gotham to eliminate crime.

Comment: mad architect? Sounds like a good plan. At least worth trying. God knows the vigilante route hasn't been terribly effective...